# Is there a better way to move a sprite using the keyboard with Pygame?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite

Currently, I have small image that I move using the D and A keys on the keyboard. The code works just how I want it to, but it seems to be a bit unnecessarily complicated. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

In the main loop, my code checks to see what key is pressed through the events, but after that, if a key is no longer pressed, it checks to see if another key is pressed, just in case a user pressed a key while another key was initially pressed.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

SCREENX = 640
SCREENY = 480

LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'


class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file):
        super().__init__()
        temp_image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.moving = False
        self.direction = RIGHT

    def start_move(self, direction):
        self.moving = True
        if direction != self.direction:
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.direction = direction

    def stop_move(self):
        if self.moving:
            self.moving = False

    def move(self):
        if self.direction == RIGHT:
            self.rect.x += 5
        if self.direction == LEFT:
            self.rect.x -= 5

    def update(self):
        if self.moving:
            self.move()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENX, SCREENY))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    girl = Character("assets/girl.png")
    girl.rect.x = SCREENX/2
    girl.rect.y = SCREENY - girl.rect.height

    sprites.add(girl)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if not girl.moving:
                    if event.key == K_d:
                        girl.start_move(RIGHT)
                    if event.key == K_a:
                        girl.start_move(LEFT)
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_a or event.key == K_d:
                    girl.stop_move()
                    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys_pressed[K_d]:
                        girl.start_move(RIGHT)
                    if keys_pressed[K_a]:
                        girl.start_move(LEFT)

        surface.fill((255, 255, 255))
        sprites.update()
        sprites.draw(surface)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get rid of most of the event handling, you can generalize your main loop, and you can get rid of some fields of your `Character` class.

See my explanatory notes in the comments:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

SCREENX = 640
SCREENY = 480


class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        temp_image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        # only to the flipping of the image once
        self.image_r = pygame.transform.scale(temp_image, (100, 100))
        self.image_l = pygame.transform.flip(self.image_r, True, False)
        self.image = self.image_l
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        move = 0
        if pressed_keys[K_d]: move += 1
        if pressed_keys[K_a]: move -= 1
        self.rect.move_ip(move*5, 0)

        # check which direction we're facing and set the image
        self.image = self.image_l if move < 0 else self.image_r

def main():
    pygame.init()
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENX, SCREENY))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    girl = Character("assets/girl.png")
    girl.rect.x = SCREENX / 2
    girl.rect.y = SCREENY - girl.rect.height

    sprites.add(girl)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # since we are in a function, we can simply return.
            # we don't care here what happens after we quit the main loop
            if event.type == QUIT: return pygame.quit()

        # get all pressed keys, and just let all sprites 
        # decide what they want to do with it
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # you could wrap this information in a more
        # general container represeting the game state
        # See how the game loop does not care what a 
        # Sprite does with this information
        sprites.update(keys_pressed)

        surface.fill((255, 255, 255))
        sprites.draw(surface)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! This does simplify things a lot. In regards to the sprite's update function, if I want to add features such as jumping or throwing, should I implement that all in update(), or should I add functions to Character and call them from update?

Comment: @dominikm For readability, it's often advisable to extract code into its own function.